# TeamCity\buildAgent\work\1c156ddc5607824e\LRMS.WebServices.sln.metaproj error MSB3202:

Tags: teamcity

I have a project with multiple folder structures. I work on 2 different projects and on both the when I compile and publish a solution through Visual studio manually all works fine without any issues. but when I try to run the same solution through Team city I get lot of errors. Since I am new to team city is there any particular settings to be done on team city to compile the solution.

Comment: Are you building using a MSBuild step? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Yes i am building using MSBuild step. and i am getting the below error.

Comment: AllLocations\AllLocationsUserControl.ascx.cs(1013, 45): error CS1061: 'projecttest.BL.ClassFiles.AllocationBL' does not contain a definition for 'GetDocsForLocation' and no extension method 'GetDocsForLocation' accepting a first argument of type ''projecttest.BL.ClassFiles.AllocationBL' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
AllLocations\AllLocationsUserControl.ascx.cs(1039, 107): error CS0117: ''projecttest.Common.Classes.AppConstants' does not contain a definition for 'AL_DocumentInComplete'

Comment: ''projecttest.BL.ClassFiles.AllocationBL' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
CurrentLocation\CurrentLocationUserControl.ascx.cs(853, 107): error CS0117: ''projecttest.Common.Classes.AppConstants' does not contain a definition for 'AL_DocumentInComplete'
CurrentLocation\CurrentLocationUserControl.ascx.cs(822, 45): error CS1061: 'ACS.GRM.Phoenix.BL.ClassFiles.AllocationBL' does not contain a definition for 'GetDocsForLocation' and no extension method 'GetDocsForLocation' accepting a first argument of type

Comment: Are you sure you're transferring all the code over to TeamCity? Perhaps you have some files locally (so all builds fine locally) that you haven't added to your VCS, so TeamCity isn't seeing them (so builds fail)?

Comment: how do i make sure that i am transferring all the code over teamcity, is there any ways to check that or do i need to make any configurations.

Comment: Make a clean checkout somewhere else (in a clean workspace) and try to build the project. Or ask a colleague to try and build it. Depending on the VCS you use, you may also want to run `git status` or `p4 reconcile` or whatever to see if some files are still to be added to your VCS.